# When predicting, what are the valid values for dataFormat?

Tags: google-cloud-ml

#### Problem

Using the REST API, I have trained and deployed a model that I now want to use for prediction. I've [defined the collections](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/preparing-models#adding_input_and_output_collections_to_the_graph) for prediction input and output and uploaded a json file [formatted accordingly](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/getting-predictions#preparing_your_input_data) to the cloud storage. However, when trying to [create a prediction job](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_GB#p/ml/v1beta1/ml.projects.jobs.create) I cannot figure out what value to use for the `dataFormat` field, which is a required parameter. Is there any way to list all valid values?

#### What I've tried

My requests look like the one below. I've tried `JSON`, `NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON` (like when importing data into BigQuery), and even the json mime type `application/json`, in pretty much all different cases I can think of (upper and lower combined with snake, camel, etc.).

```
{
  "jobId": "my_predictions_123",
  "predictionInput": {
    "modelName": "projects/myproject/models/mymodel",
    "inputPaths": [
      "gs://model-bucket/data/testset.json"
    ],
    "outputPath": "gs://model-bucket/predictions/0/",
    "region": "us-central1",
    "dataFormat": "JSON"
   },
   "predictionOutput": {
     "outputPath": "gs://my-bucket/predictions/1/"
   }
}
```

All my attempts have only gotten me this back though:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid value at 'job.prediction_input.data_format' (TYPE_ENUM), \"JSON\"",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "job.prediction_input.data_format",
            "description": "Invalid value at 'job.prediction_input.data_format' (TYPE_ENUM), \"JSON\""
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Cloud ML API reference document https://cloud.google.com/ml/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.jobs#DataFormat, the data format field in your request should be "TEXT" for all text inputs (including JSON, CSV, etc).

Comment: It runs now, but my all my jobs fail after about 10-11 minutes and return "internal error". The [logs](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs) don't tell me anything more either, they just end after "Job my_predictions_123 is queued.". Do you know of any problems on Google's side or how I could debug it? Thank you very much for your help!